# Reading a SmartMedia card in Lubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, mount, lubuntu

I have this old digital camera who's only means of saving photos is a smart media card (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SmartMedia).
I connect this smart media card to a Belkin smart card reader, basically an older model of this (https://www.belkin.com/us/support-product?pid=01t80000002x0lJAAQ).
Now I want to connect the Belkin reader to my laptop running Lubuntu and be able to view the pictures on the smart card.
Once I connect the reader I see multiple "Generic STORAGE DEVICES" detected and once I click on any of them I get the error message that no media is connected and that the path is not mounted.
I was wondering what steps I can take to read the data from the card, if possible.

I have a 64 bit system

```
OS Info:
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
```

EDIT: So I ran journalctl --follow and got the following results, it's too long for a comment so I am adding it here.

It seems it detects it but it fails to read:

```
Jan 29 15:14:25 ndrb-pc kernel: sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] 32000 512-byte logical blocks: (16.4 MB/15.6 MiB)
Jan 29 15:14:25 ndrb-pc kernel:  sdb: sdb1
Jan 29 15:15:26 ndrb-pc systemd-udevd[328]: sdb: Worker [4023] processing SEQNUM=7496 is taking a long time
Jan 29 15:17:25 ndrb-pc kernel: sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s                     
Jan 29 15:17:25 ndrb-pc kernel: sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 29 15:17:25 ndrb-pc kernel: sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
Jan 29 15:17:25 ndrb-pc kernel: sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Data phase error
Jan 29 15:17:25 ndrb-pc kernel: sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 7c 80 00 00 08 00
Jan 29 15:17:25 ndrb-pc kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 31872 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0                                                                                
Jan 29 15:17:26 ndrb-pc systemd-udevd[328]: sdb: Worker [4023] processing SEQNUM=7496 killed
```

Comment: I just grabbed an old SD-card from a pile used by old digital cameras I no longer use, inserted into USB-media convertor (*single media type unlike yours*) and plug it in, and a pop-up appears asking what I'd like to do; eg. I have an option to *Open in file manager* which opens `pcmanfm-qt` (ie. Lubuntu's file-manager app) which lets me navigate down the DCIM .. down to photos ..   I needed to do nothing more; though if I did I' use terminal commands so messages appear on screen and & I can recognize/deal-with any error(s) from bad-media etc.  No special tools/steps were required.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect the reader, then keep watching as you insert the card. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply, i edited the post with the results of journalctl --follow